# How do I recover accidentally deleted /usr/bin/ssh-copy-id?

Tags: ssh

I'm on my work's computer and I accidentally ran 'rm /usr/bin/ssh-copy-id'.
Is there a way to bring it back?

Comment: In that case, please accept the answer by clicking the tick under the voting buttons, so that it turns green.

Answer (score 4):

Just reinstall the `openssh-client`.

```
sudo apt install --reinstall openssh-client
```